# Can i return empty array in HttpInterceptor when error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need this to handle errors where I have to display empty "lists" in dropdowns. This my interceptor

```
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError((err) => {
  // check because invalid password return 401
  if (err.status === 401 && !this.router.url.includes('/auth')) {
    // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    location.reload();
  }
  // Eror alert
  if (this.router.url.includes('/auth')) {
    this.message.error(
        err.error ?? err.statusText,
        { nzDuration: 5000,
          nzPauseOnHover: true },
    );
  }
  console.log(err);
  // I want to return empty array here
  return throwError(err);
}));
}
```

So I can edit all my getSomethingMethod() with catchError but can i get this with interceptors?

example in comments not work.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhtclm?file=src/app/error.ts
not trigger "res" section

Comment: [import { of } from 'rxjs'](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of) and `return of(err)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError((err) => {
    console.log(err);

    // would resolve to error
    // return throwError(() => err.message);

    // will resovle in complete
    // return EMPTY

    // Will resolve in next with empty array
    return of(new HttpResponse({ body: [] }));
  }));
}
```

NOTE:

Why did I return HttpResponse in `of()`**?**

This is because you have to return an observable of type HttpResponse values in the interceptor to continue the call. Other values are ignored

Comment: its not work for me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhtclm?file=src/app/error.ts. I dont get empty array in res section

Comment: If you want the empty array in the res, then use of([]), not throwError([])

Comment: I have type eror in interceptor if do this.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahashg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ferror.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I have compiled the proper solution to return empty array and also edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
In this section, you can show your error to the user in the form of a message or dialog and return EMPTY at the end

```
import { EMPTY } from 'rxjs';


catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
     
        if (error) {
          showMessage('messages.tryAgain');
        } 

        return EMPTY
})
```